# How to display a certain number of array items in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, jquery, coffeescript

I have an array and I want to display only 4 items at a time and when I click on Next it will display the 4 next items.
View Code :

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th></th>

</tr>
<% count = 0 %> 
<% while count < 4%>
  <tr class="match_row" value="<%=count%>">
    <th id="left_competitor"><%= @matches[count][0].title %></th>
    <% (1..6).each do |i|%>
      <th>  <input type="radio" class="group_<%=count%>" name="<%=count%>" value="<%= i%>"><br></th>
    <% end %>
    <th id="right_competitor"> <%= @matches[count][1].title %></th>
  </tr>
  <br />
  <% count += 1 %>
<% end %>
<br />
</table>
<input id="save_votes" type="button" value="Next">
```

Now here is the CoffeeScript code :

```
move_to_next_match = ->
  $("#save_votes").click -> display_next_competitors()

display_next_competitors = ->
  project_id = document.getElementById("project_id").value
  match_rows = $('.match_row')
  results = []
  for i in [0...match_rows.length]
    do (i) ->
      radios = $(".group_#{i}")
      for j in [0...radios.length]
        do (j) ->
          if radios[j].checked
            count = radios[j].getAttribute 'name'
            number = radios[j].getAttribute 'value'
            results.push("#{count} #{number}")
  data = "{\"get_matches_results\": \"#{results}-#{project_id}-#{marker}\"}"
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST"
  url: "projectss/pca_results"
  data: "data=" + data
  })
  location.reload(true);
```

My idea is to let the variable count in view (<%count = 0%>) take the value of a variable instead of 0 but I can't figure out how to do this.
Any ideas ?

Comment: You don't need `do (i) ->` and `do (j) ->` in your code. You only need the `do (x) ->` syntax for capturing values referenced by inner functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a lot of logic in your view templates, reminds me more of PHP.

Maybe you can table a look at this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

Ryan uses a Gem to handle the pagination (Lookup Kaminari or WillPaginate) and then uses unobstructive jQuery to handle the AJAX component.

Comment: thanks for replying :). Now I can display as much items as I want, but I want to execute some code before displaying the next items.
Let me explain :
I am displaying two ideas and 6 radio_buttons, the user click on one radio_button to choose which idea he prefers the most. I want to save the result of these 4 matches before moving to the next 4. Do you have any idea how to it ?

Comment: You'll probably want to use the same javascript function that handles the pagination (before $.getScript) and send another AJAX request to your save method at the controller than handles the saving. 

Just write another Javscript function that gets executed, picks up the values to save from the DOM and then sends them to your controller.

Comment: I have another question : I want to execute some JQuery code when I am on the last page. Can you tell me how to know that I am on the last page?

Comment: In WillPaginate if you paginate an object such as @matches, you should be able to do "@matches.page_count". In your view template you could check if total_entires matches params[:page] and if so, put in a Javascript hook to run your final jQuery

Comment: "@matches.page_count" didn't work, I got this error : undefined method `page_count' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x0000000c5c55b0>.
But actually, all I needed was just params[:page]. Now it's working thanks

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure. It's been a long time since I used willPaginate. I'm glad you found a solution though :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question what problem you're experiencing, but I'm guessing that it has to do with the code

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST"
url: "projectss/pca_results"
data: "data=" + data
})
location.reload(true);
```

which sends a request to the server that potentially changes the page's content, then immediately refreshes the page without waiting for a response. There's a race condition there: Sometimes the page will refresh before its content is updated, sometimes after. You should instead write

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST"
url: "projectss/pca_results"
data: "data=" + data
success: -> location.reload(true);
})
```

to ensure that the page is refreshed only after the update is processed. Or, better yet, write a `success` callback that updates the HTML on the page then and there, rather than refreshing the entire page. Your users will thank you.

Comment: Actually I used the Gem WillPaginate suggested by Blake and it worked but now I can't execute the CoffeeScript code before displaying the next items